# UIButton _setTitleFrozen crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, crash, uibutton

I have weird crash related to UIButton class. I have not found anything similar on SO yet. The log I get comes from Crashlytics so I also don't know which part of code is causing the issue. I put crash log below, may be some of you have already found out what is creating the problem.

EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xd1712d18

```
0 libobjc.A.dylib   objc_msgSend + 5 _setTitleFrozen: 
1 UIKit 32-[UIButton _beginTitleAnimation]_block_invoke853 + 28
2 UIKit -[UIViewAnimationBlockDelegate_didEndBlockAnimation:finished:context:] + 308
3 UIKit -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 184
4 UIKit -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 70
5 QuartzCore CA::Layer::run_animation_callbacks(void*) + 234
6 libdispatch.dylib _dispatch_client_callout + 22
7 libdispatch.dylib _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 712
8 CoreFoundation __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE_ + 8
9 CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopRun + 1512
10 CoreFoundation CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 476
11 CoreFoundation CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
12 GraphicsServices GSEventRunModal + 136
13 UIKit UIApplicationMain + 1440
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: The log comes from crashlytics, I have no idea what part of code is causing that...

Comment: As as per your log said, your code crashed in block of animation. Check your code where you implemented block animation and trying to change title of button.

Comment: I do not perform any custom animation. That just comes from system behaviour. If it had been such a trivial thing I would not ask here. The only person who might help me is probably the one met with the problem before. Someone must got that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the button type from System to Custom resolved this crash for me.

In my case this crash occurred because I was changing the button title right before removing it from the view hierarchy (by dismissing its parent view's VC) while the title change animation was still running.